# syntax error in function in a module, OCaml

Tags: module, syntax-error, ocaml

Hi my following code gives a "Syntax Error" and i have no idea why...

Any basic mistake you can see?

```
(* ajouter_itineraire: itineraire -> plan -> plan *)
let  ajouter_itineraire (i: itineraire) (p: plan) = match p with
   | Vide ->[i]
   | Ilist l ->if itineraire_existe(i.num) then
       Err("Itineraire deja present") else i::p.Ilist
```

Err is an exception taking a string as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to return the exception as a value. I think you want to say `raise (Err "Itineraire deja present")`. Also `p.Ilist` looks wrong. Most likely this should be just `l`.

Comment: Right, and right... Thanks, I'm a beginner in OCaml and without these 2 mistakes my code runs well... when I think I've spent so much time on this ^^'